# Why App crash when Image height change in UWP?

Tags: uwp

Here is the XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="Black">


    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Source="Image/L.png" Name="L"></Image>
        <Image Source="Image/BG.png" Grid.Column="1" Name="BG" SizeChanged="BG_SizeChanged"></Image>
        <Image Source="Image/R.png" Grid.Column="2" Name="R"></Image>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I wanna that height of L and R are the same as BG.In WPF I can binding ActualHeight to do it easily,however in UWP it failed.And I read some topic in stackoverflow that knowed I can not do it like that any more.
So I use `SizeChanged` to do it,here is the code:

```
 private void BG_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            L.Height = e.NewSize.Height;
            R.Height = e.NewSize.Height;
        }
```

Well,when I ran the APP,and resize the window casually,the APP crashed.Strangely visual studio reported no error but just highlighted these code:
[image]
These code are not write by me by just default in `App.g.i.cs`

What's wrong with this?And how can I solve this problem?Thank you.

Comment: @kennyzx Sorry I don't know your actual meaning,you mean I should to binding the acutalheight in Loaded event hanlder but not in XAML?

Comment: I delete my comment as I realize I did not read carefully. The exception may be triggered by the fact that by resizing L and R, BG’s size is affected as well, which triggers more BG_SizeChanged event.

Comment: The simplest solution could be using the Image’s Stretch property. There are four possible values, try them if they can do the magic.

Comment: @kennyzx However what's the problem with my code?The code seems not complicated but I don't know the probelm.

Comment: @kennyzx Or is there has any ways can make the image height the same without binding or SizeChanged?

Comment: Add a trace point to the method BG_SizeChanged. And print some message when the trace point is hit, see if the method is called repeatedly and eventually leads to stack overflow.

Comment: I thinked over of this,and I used debug.writeline to output the e.NewSize.Height and all of this property is ok.But When the programe set the image height to it,the App crashed.And strangely sometimes I resized it indefinitely for 1 second then it crash and sometimes I resized it indefinitely for 5 second then it crash.It crash with no rules. @kennyzx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is

> Layout cycle detected.  Layout could not complete.

Which is not quite useful to indicate the root cause of the issue. However it does indicate some sort of `cycle` (that is function being called endlessly).

After adding a debug log to the `BG_SizeChanged` method, I notice there are many! hits before the app crash, that means `BG_SizeChanged` is called repeatedly until the call stack is full. Paul was right.

The call stack is

BG is resized -> BG_SizeChanged is called -> L/R are resized in the BG_SizeChanged method -> BG is resized (since it takes up whatever space left since the column width is defined as *)  =>>>>Thus entering an endless loop until the app crash.

**The solution**

The hard part is the original size of the three images play an important role in the layout, they may have different height/width ratio too. So far, I find the best solution without having to calculate the "right" absolute size for each of them is

```
<Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="400">
        <Image Source="Image/L.png" 
        Name="L" Stretch="Fill" />
        <Image Source="Image/BG.png" 
        Grid.Column="1" 
        Name="BG" Stretch="Fill" />
        <Image Source="Image/R.png" 
        Grid.Column="2" Name="R" Stretch="Fill" />
    </StackPanel>
</Viewbox>
```

The key is

1. Setting an explicit `Height` to the `StackPanel`, 400, or 500, the value does not really matter, it just sets an upper limit to how tall all the images can be resized.
2. Setting each Image's `Stretch` property to `Fill` so they grow to take up all the available height.
3. Finally, the magical `ViewBox` container, it helps to resize the whole `StackPanel` when the window is resized while keeping the height/width ratio of the `StackPanel`. That is why the `Height` of `StackPanel` does not matter.

Comment: Oh,I know your meaning now.It fall into a endless loop,so it crashed.Thank you,your idea that using viewbox is good!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the callback method is called when the image is initially loaded. You then set the image height which calls the callback method (handler) again, which then calls it again since you just changed the height...stackoverflow maybe.

Comment: I suppose not,the APP crash seems has no rules.Sometimes I resized it indefinitely for 1 second then it crash and sometimes I resized it indefinitely for 5 second then it crash.